# Is it safe to modify the content of a string variable through a pointer?

Tags: delphi

Consider I have a procedure with `Str` parameter passed by reference, and I want to modify content of the given variable through the procedure, e.g.

```
procedure Replace(var Str: string);
var
  PStr: PChar;
  i: Integer;
begin
  PStr := @Str[1];
  for i := 1 to Length(Str) do begin
    PStr^ := 'x';
    Inc(PStr);
  end;
end;
```

Is it an acceptable pointer usage? I'm not sure whether it has a memory leak.

What really happen in `PStr := @Str[1]`, does compiler make a copy of `Str` internally, or what?

Is this kind of code optimization worth?

Comment: Your cast is not acceptable, it will crash when an empty string is passed to your procedure. Use `PStr := PChar(Str)` instead, it will return a `PChar` pointing to `#0` instead of crashing.

Comment: @mghie, thanks for the suggestion, but for an empty string case, I could just add a pre-emptive checking before it, e.g. `if Str = '' then Exit`

Comment: Another way to write your function is simply `Str := StringOfChar('x', Length(Str))`.

Comment: @Astaroth: Yes, if you prefer to write code yourself that the compiler would provide for free. Note that you essentially duplicate a check that the loop will perform anyway.

Comment: @Astaroth: your solution sounds like premature optimization to me; only optimize when speed is an issue. If it is not an issue, then use the suggesion by Rob Kennedy.

Comment: Note that I just provided a simple case example, the real one is to replace every particular character with a certain character in a string. The string itself might be huge (more than 100 MB). In that case, of course, any small optimization would be worth.

Comment: Why access the string that way when you can simply access it like an array? Instead of 'PStr^  := ' why not 'Str[i] := '?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it an acceptable pointer usage?

You need to make sure that you don't call

```
PStr := @Str[1];
```

for an empty string, as that would crash. The easiest way to do that is to replace that line with

```
PStr := PChar(Str);
```

so that the compiler will make sure that either a pointer to the first char of the string, or a pointer to  `#0` is returned. As Ken correctly pointed out in a comment there is no call to `UniqueString()` in this case, so you would need to do it yourself.

> I'm not sure whether it has a memory leak.

No, there is no memory leak. Obtaining a pointer to a string character will call `UniqueString()` internally, but that will happen for write access to a string character too, so there's nothing special about the character pointer.

> What really happen in PStr := @Str[1], does compiler make a copy of Str internally, or what?

No, it just makes sure that the string is unique (so that write access through the pointer does not change the contents of any other string that shares the same data). Afterwards it returns a pointer to that character in the string, which you can then treat as any other `PChar` variable, pass it to API functions, increment it and so on.

> Is this kind of code optimization worth?

It is not only worth it, it is necessary to really achieve good performance for large strings. The reason for this is that the compiler is not smart enough to only call `UniqueString()` once, but it will insert calls to it for each write access to a character in the string. So if you process a large string character by character you will have a big overhead from all these calls.

Comment: Casting a string to PChar will *not* call UniqueString internally.  It needs to be done manually. But calling *PStr := @Str[1]* will call UniqueString internally. So if he replaces it with a simple typecast, he needs to call UniqueString manually.

Comment: AFAIK, the problem with `PChar(Str)` is that we need to call `UniqueString()` manually before making a change of content through it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe, as long as you don't go beyond the bounds of the string.  The string has metadata attached that tells how long it is, and if you write beyond the length of the string, you won't leak memory, but you could corrupt it.

Answer (score 1):

If `Str` is passed by reference, why would you need another pointer to the string? Apart from that, there should be no memory leak: `PStr` is initialized with the adress of the first element of the string and then incremented, so it will always point to one of the characters in your string.

The compile does not make a copy of `Str` internally. One of the uses for pointers is to avoid making copies. When you say

```
PStr := @Str[1]
```

is that `PStr` will now store the *adress* of `Str[1]`, that is, the adress of the first char in the string.

Comment: Are you *sure* the compiler doesn't make a copy? I've seen it insert calls to `UniqueString`, but I don't know what the rules are for when it does that. Definitely for *writing* to a string via the bracket operators, but possibly also for getting a pointer to a character that way. Even if the compiler does make a copy, though, it's not a memory leak; the new copy is stored in `Str`.

Comment: @Largerbaer, I tried to use pointer to make its execution much faster instead of `Str[i] := 'x'`. I toke speed into account when a code was inside a loop.

Comment: @Astaroth, execution certainly isn't going to be *much* faster. It might be a *little* faster, but that's something you could easily determine for yourself by *measuring*. That's how you determine whether an optimization is worth it. You might attain the same improvement by temporarily disabling range checking.

Comment: @Rob, thank you so much for your note and the range checking tip.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: "Certainly"? Using `PChar` instead of indexed string access in such a simple loop as in the question takes only about 13% of the time on my system (5.1 vs. 39 milliseconds for a 10 MByte string). So for any performance-sensitive non-trivial code (i.e. can't be replaced by `StringOfChar()`) using `PChar` is probably a worthy optimization. It removes all but one call to `UniqueString()`. It has nothing whatsoever to do with range checking.

Comment: Note that I just provided a simple case example, the real one is to replace every particular character with a certain character in a string. The string itself might be huge (more than 100 MB). In that case, of course, any small optimization would be worth.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this will work for AnsiString and PAnsiChar, but will it still work for unicode strings in Delphi 2009 and above? I think it should, because both, a char of a string (str[i]) and the char pointed to by PChar, should be 2 bytes in size.

Could somebody with more experience with unicode strings please confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm that works for Delphi 2009 and above. I've been using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score -1):

As in D2010, looks like codegen employs copy-on-write on such construct

```
Unit9.pas.34: S := 'abcd';
004B32EF 8D45F4           lea eax,[ebp-$0c]
004B32F2 BA98334B00       mov edx,$004b3398
004B32F7 E89C35F5FF       call @UStrLAsg
Unit9.pas.35: P := @S[1];
004B32FC 8D45F4           lea eax,[ebp-$0c]
004B32FF E8343FF5FF       call @UniqueStringU    ; <== here you are
004B3304 8945F0           mov [ebp-$10],eax
Unit9.pas.36: Exit;
004B3307 EB61             jmp $004b336a
```

by the way, generic referencing `P := @S` does not emit UniqueString.

As conclusion, i do not recommend to count on codegen's internals and use recommended `PChar(S)` construct (emits one `xStrToPxChar` call as overhead)